# React: should get url in child component times or should get it once in ancestor then pass down as props layer by layer?

Tags: reactjs

I have an ancestor component , and a Name component which is the 4th generation child of Index. There is a new feature I have to add to this app, to make Name s to be red or be bold or add some prefix according to url params, such as "&red=true&bold=true&prefix=true".

I am really tired of passing single prop layer by layer, because I have to add "propA={this.props.propA}" layer by layer, if there is a new param, then add again layer by layer.

Or maybe I should pass all the props, which I don't like, that means pass all props layer by layer.

The third way is getting url params in the Name component constructor itself, then, one done, all done. But, it will get url params in each Name initializion scope, so that will be a lot, I am worring about the performance or the logic of my way is not right.

So, which way is better:

1 passing single props layer by layer, add prop to pass if there is a new one to pass layer by layer.
2 passing all props layer by layer.
3 get url params in the smallest component which will use it.

or is there a another way?

Thank you.

Index.js

```
class Index extends React.component {
  render() {
    return <A />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Index/>,
  document.getElementById("App")
);
```

A.js

```
class A extends React.component {
  render() {
    return <B />
  }
}
```

B.js

```
class A extends React.component {
  render() {
    return <C />
  }
}
```

C.js

```
class A extends React.component {
  render() {
    return <Name />
  }
}
```

Name.js

```
class Name extends React.component {
  construtor(props){
    super(props);
    this.name = null;
    this.namePrefix = getUrlParam(window.location.search).nameprefix //boolean
  }
  render() {
    if (this.namePrefix) {
        this.name = 'The Genius ' + 'Jack';
    }
    else {
        this.name = 'Jack';
    }
    return <div>{this.name}<div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code examples of what you're doing so we can suggest improvements? Generally speaking, you should pass down information via props, it's the simpler solution, and if you have propTypes validation it's not too much of a hassle to manage. There is nothing wrong with doing `<Component {...this.props} />`, if you need to do it to save time.

Answer (score 1):

Using MobX or the new React Context API you can have selected items available to the whole DOM tree and any component that needs some attribute can subscribe to them.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the place in your application where you should think about introducing Redux (or Flux). In a nutshell, every component will be able to trigger action that gets data from unique store that holds all the data for your application. Props will flow from root component down the component tree and every component will be able to 'ask' for data anytime triggering action that gets data from backend or extracting it via props.

More about Redux : https://redux.js.org/introduction